# blending two fragment shaders with opengl/glsl

Tags: javascript, html, opengl, glsl, shader

I have two shaders that do different things. The first loads an image generated realtime from a html5 canvas, the other is generated by a string that represents the code for the shader.

Basically, I would like to overlay the texture over the first shader, but not have the shader generated by the code have any effect on the texture. The texture itself has its own shader.

How can I display both shaders (the one with the texture would have a white transparency so the generated shader below would be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the blending operations see [here](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm) (yes its an old link but its still valid).

Draw the underlying triangles with the shader, then enable blending and draw the other trangles with the other shader, not also that the second shader must write the Alhpa value (eg. 0.7).

About your terminology:

Saying that a texture has a shader is plainly wrong, shaders fetch textures so you basically see only a shader that does operations on textures.

Comment: thanks! what i meant by the texture having a shader is that i meant i have a separate fragment shader that fetches a texture and does the operations on its data it in its own way, separate from the other shader generated by the code. but thanks again, i'm still learning! :D